# Conditionally select a list node in iReport?

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

How can I select a node from XML datasource by condition?
Eg I have an xml that has multiple customer nodes. I now want to select all the customer whose type=business.

```
<list>
  <customer>
   <type>business</type>
   <amount>10</amount>
  </customer>
  <customer>
   <type>private</type>
   <amount>20</amount>
  </customer>
</list>
```

What is the iReport jrxml expression for this? Do I have to use XPATH to locate the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use XPath. Try this one:

```
/list/customer[type='business']
```

Comment: That would give me the first element. I want to display all elements repeatedly.

Comment: Well ok, that's how I select them, but when I drag this into the designer and use `/list/customer[type='business']/type`, only the first found element is displayed (in my file there a multiple business customer elements). Somewhing is still missing here...

Comment: Try adding a subreport to your report with a XML datasource using the XPath provided in the answer.

Comment: I was not of the fact I have to create subreports as jrxml files and include them in the main reports. That makes sense. OK now I know how to display subreports. But what if I acutally want to sum up a property of each business customer, eg the `<amount>`? That's probably not solved using subreports. I think I could reuse the xpath selection above. But how can I then explicit sum a subpropety of that selection?

Comment: If you need the total amount inside the subreport, it's easy. Just add a field in the subreport callled `amount` and add a report variable called `totalAmount` of type `sum` whose expression is `$F{amount}`. Then use `$V{totalAmount}` to print its value.